# unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory when running docker build

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, cpython, amazon-ecr

I was trying to create a docker image for my python script and upload it to AWS ECR and then use it in Lambda. Our python runtime is 3.8 shown on the AWS console so I just followed this manual:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-base

But I got the error when I run docker build -t image-name .

```
#6 14.02 gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/var/lang/include/python3.8 -c bitarray/_bitarray.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/bitarray/_bitarray.o
#6 14.02 unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
#6 14.02 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I double checked and I have gcc installed on my macOS:

```
Warning: gcc 11.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 11.2.0, run:
brew reinstall gcc
```

Would appreciate some help on resolving this. thanks!

EDIT:
This issue originates from me unable to import a CPython library cytoolz when running my script on Lambda, so I consulted these issues to simulate the runtime using docker.
https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1717#issuecomment-445821158
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1456#issuecomment-866862759

If there is a better way to import cytoolz without using docker I would also def appreciate some hints!

Thx!!

Comment: gcc needs to be installed in the Docker container. The build process doesn't use any software installed on the host (except docker itself).

Comment: @Hans Kilian
hey thanks Hans. I've updated my docker file to 
`RUN yum groups mark install "Development Tools"
RUN yum groups mark convert "Development Tools"
RUN yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`
However I still get 
`executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum groupinstall "Development Tools": exit code: 1`
I consulted this [post](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1310043) but with no avail. Do you have any hints on how to work around this?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have much experience with yum or aws images. If the base image you use is Debian or Ubuntu based, I'd try installing gcc with `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential`.

Comment: Does anyone have updated instructions for this? The 3.12 container doesnt know what yum is, and it doesnt know what apt-get is.

Answer (score 4):

Add the below commands to get requried things installed.

`RUN yum update -y`

`RUN yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y`

Sample Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

RUN yum update -y

RUN yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y

RUN pip --version
```

Comment: Note: This does *not* seem to work with the 3.12 (current) containers. It doesnt know what "Yum" is. Actually neither do I , I assume its a redhat version of apt-get?